# Control a service on a remote computer with only a local admin user (with powershell or/and c#)

Tags: c#, windows, service, wmi

I'm user in the active directory and there is a remote Computer outside this active directory.
I want to start and stop a service on this computer.
Of course a have the credentials of the local admin.

```
var startService = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "sc.exe",
        Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", "\\192.168.0.5", "stop", "TestService"),
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UserName = "user",
        Password = securePassword,
        Domain = "localhost"
    }
};

try
{
    startService.Start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
```

It throws an exception, that the crentials are wrong.

> Unknown Username or Bad Password

I tried to set StartInfo.Domain to the remote computer name, but this didn't work either.

Need some help here.

Comment: I have no special knowledge in this area, but I would be very surprised if this is possible. This is the sort of thing that security and credentials are supposed to ensure can't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote side

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

Client side

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName -Credential Get-Credential -ScriptBlock {ls c:\}
```

In ScriptBlock I can use the e.g. Get-Service Command to control a service on the remote side.

In C# it locks like this

```
// Install-Package System.Management.Automation 
var credential = new PSCredential("User", securePassword);

PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
ps.AddParameter("ComputerName", "ComputerName");
ps.AddParameter("Credential", credential);
ps.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", ScriptBlock.Create("Get-Service -Name ServiceName"));

var result = ps.Invoke();

dynamic temp = result.First();
var status = temp.Status;
```